# Flowtype: shorthand for type with all fields as Maybes

Tags: flowtype

With Flow, sometimes I want to represent an object of a certain type but where any field may be `undefined` or `null`.

For instance, when validating an object of type `T`, prior to the validation I know I have something that looks like a `T` but may have some fields missing. After the validation succeeds, I *know* I have a `T` and won't need to nullcheck all the fields each time I use them.

```
type T = { a: number, b: number }
type MaybeT = { a: ?number, b: ?number }

const validate = (candidate: MaybeT): T => {
  if (!candidate.a || !candidate.b) {
    throw 'Invalid'
  }

  return { a: candidate.a, b: candidate.b }
}

const maybeT: MaybeT = getInputFromUser()

const t: T = validate(maybeT)

doStuffKnowingAllFieldsOfTAreDefined(t)
```

Obviously, this redefinition of `MaybeT` is verbose, and if I amend `T` I now have to also remember to amend `MaybeT`.

My question:

1. Is there some sort of shorthand for this in Flow, i.e. something like `$WithAllFieldsMaybe<T>`, so I can just derive `MaybeT` from `T` without having to manually do it?
2. If not, is there a better pattern for this, without needing to use two separate types? As far as I can tell, there is no way to let Flow 'know' that all fields are present after `validate` because, for instance, I could set the fields back to null after `validate` has run - so I don't see a way to use a single type here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allow any field to be `undefined`:

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

type OptionalPerson = $Shape<Person>
```

[flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKeATgM5wB2YAvGAN6phiUCGAtngFxhkYkBLSgHMANEzCth3FgFd2AI1KoAvumz4wAeRwYBVVjGLkqtMABIAygAtW+ADzGKlAHwTUUWZQDGe0zkFKDCcqAAp8E0oeHT82I1JnAEoGCQEoMFCAQgjnADo2TmSSPAxZEkp3Zm8qChg8XPhhcISqfI4CAFIwAFZE1XQAoWCWylD6FT7BoJDR+hZ2ngByACs4a0pFsAnUKeHIsclpHgBmAAYtycC95wOCmRW1jdFDmTOLoA)

---

Allow any field to be `null`:

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

type NullablePerson = $ObjMap<Person, <V>(V) => ?V>
```

[flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKeATgM5wB2YAvGAN6phiUCGAtngFxhkYkBLSgHMANEzCth3FgFd2AI1KoAvumz4wAOVkwYrBTDzFyVWmAAkAeQUArALKscAHhMVKosM4BqAPgAU3gCUtL5gAPx+EqhQspQAxhgCZjiClBhuVP74ppQ8OnoGRpmUIYzMAlBg-gCEOe4AdGycISR4GLIklBLxVBRGDfDC2aSNzQQApGAArEGq6KlCGaNZ9CwcMpS6MJ5Sm9tgKnOL6SX+a+M8AOS2cAAWlFe70jxbeofHacu55+ucr9tnjIAMwABg+qBO33cv0uYBu90eQJ4YI+QA)

---

Allow any field to be `undefined` or `null`:

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

type MaybePerson = $Shape<$ObjMap<Person, <V>(V) => ?V>>
```

[flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKeATgM5wB2YAvGAN6phiUCGAtngFxhkYkBLSgHMANEzCth3FgFd2AI1KoAvumz4wAWVZYlxclVpgAJAGUAFq3wAeEwHkFAKx04bBipVFgbANQB8ABS+AJS0-mAA-AH+EqhQspQAxhgCRjiClBgeVIH4hpQ8Onp4OZRhjMwCUGCBAIT5ngB0bJxhJHgYsiSUEklUFDB4TfDCeaTNrQQApGAArCGq6MzMqBlC2RO59CqL61llgfQsHDIA5E5wFpRnYLtrmZsFR5LSPADMAAx3e4+Hx1MeBcrjdvFIZF8fhJVvsnp4XoC5DAYGC3kiYFDYf8TpwgZdrmdUTJKLJkZi-ltKAjTjwSciiR9vvcsZTqbiwMCCQywJD7isgA)

---

If you need to use this pattern a lot, you can create a reusable utility type for yourself. For example:

```
type Maybe<T> = $Shape<$ObjMap<T, <V>(V) => ?V>>

type Person = { 
  name: string, 
  age: number 
}

type MaybePerson = Maybe<Person>
```

[flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCyAhlgEZ4A8AKgHxgC8YAJAMoAWx+lzA8mQCsSOGgBowlAGq0AFJICUjegH5ptdNnxgACngBOAZzgA7RmADeqMGGPEAtngBcYAxj0BLYwHNRVsMS8nGwBXOwo9VABfDVwCEnI8XUMTM3iKSiSjY3VrVChg4wBjDHcUnA9jDEyTGXxk42c0xP0sxUtrdygwGQBCOqyAOlsHRT08DGC9Yz9CkyMYPAH4L1qWkyH7AgBSMABWeSj0a1zyzyq14xlzSIPTyurL8xtN5wByATh2Y1ewG9Q7871K7+QLOADMAAZfrcKoCssDhkF3p9vuIAkFIdC-CdYQ8ES8QjAYGjQYSYFiAXinoi3h8vq8SUFjMEiRTcRd8Q5nMyiYzwVC-pSOdSCcj6XywJi-scgA)

---

References:

`$Shape`: Undocumented in Flow docs. You can read about it here: http://sitr.us/2015/05/31/advanced-features-in-flow.html#shapet

`$ObjMap`: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap

Comment: Close, but it makes properties optional and not [`maybe`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-maybe-types). (`null` is not allowed for optional)

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: Actually, I'm noticing some issues with my update... it seems that using `$Shape` on an `$ObjMap` seems to be buggy and no longer type checks the properties properly :/

Comment: Oh, now I see `$ObjMap` breaks further type checks

Comment: idk, it's weird because it seems to understand that the property can be `null`/`undefined`... [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKeATgM5wB2YAvGAN6phiUCGAtngFxhkYkBLSgHMANEzCth3FgFd2AI1KoAvumz4wAWVZYlxclVpgAJAGUAFq3wAeEwHkFAKx04bBipVFgbANQB8ABQAlLT+YAD8Af4SqFCylADGGAJGOIKUGB5UgfiGlDw6enjZlKGMzLmkngB0bJw8fBnCwQDcqkA)

Comment: `$ObjMap` doesn't seem to work as expected [try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKeATgM5wB2YAvGAN6phiUCGAtngFxhkYkBLSgHMANEzCth3FgFd2AI1KoAvumz4wAWVZYlxclVpgAJAHkFAKx04APAYqVRYWwDUAfAAoAlLXdgAfg8AbglUKFlKAGMMASMcQUoMBypPfENKHh09PBTKX0ZmdMcAOjZOY35ZPGCwYGAwBTg4GDxWaiE+NoATMDgoXn4hYVUgA)

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks. Didn't just answer my question but also a bunch of related follow up questions I had :-)

Comment: Hey @davnicwil just make sure you look at this comment thread, it looks like the examples I posted with `$ObjMap` don't work correctly unfortunately. I may file an issue to `flow` and followup here.

Comment: Guys check it out, I fixed the issue in the snippets and updated the try flow examples as well. @Saad you were missing a `V` inside parens like `(V)`. Works now!